# how to convert string to class name

Tags: android, class

I am trying to convert string to class name.
My code is:

```
app.actNum = "third.class";
        in.close();
                //on test
                   //  Intent intent = new Intent(this.context,Class.forName(app.actNum));



Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Class.forName(app.actNum));
```

but get

```
  get ClassNotFoundException on Class.forName android
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When calling `Class.forName()`, you should use the class's name without the extension. So if your **class** is called`Test` and is in the **package** `mypackage.tests`, then you should use:

```
Class.forName("mypackage.tests.Test")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some problems with the path.

First, try and get the complete path :

```
String completePath = PathForClass.class.getResource(app.actNum).toString();
```

Then, all you have to do is to invoke it as you did:

```
 Class.forName(completePath.replace(".class","")
```

(As stated in the other answers, you have to remove the `.class`. )

Comment: using the Class class is not very optimized because of the slow java reflection. so calling to operations on Class is not performance wise. I do not see the benefit from doing a getResource here

Comment: Well, in case he doesn't know where the ".class" is, the getResource could be helpful.

Comment: Nope, he could do Ctrl + Shift + T and type the class name in eclipse and find it. :)

Comment: @AdelBoutros : what makes you think he is using eclipse ? ^^

Comment: Lucky guess ;) Android Dev is mostly done in eclipse these days.

Comment: @AdelBoutros Sure ... anyway, I understand that your solution is performant and aiming Eclipse while the mine is may be less performant but aims to be a little more generic :)

Comment: If the intention was to dynamically generate classes (which i doubt is the case here), I would have agreed.

Comment: what is PathForClass?