# Start new activity getting the class by a String

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a DB with the class name of many Activity, for example:

```
Activity1Name.class
Activity2Name.class
Activity3Name.class
```

etc.

this method

```
public startNewActivity(String activityName){
   Intent myActivity = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, activityName);
                startActivity(myActivity);
}
```

clearly doesn't works because the Intent

```
   Intent myActivity = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, activityName);
```

needs a class, not a String with a class name,

How could I get the class by the String activityName?

I want to avoid to declare too many intent, using only the Intent that I need in runtime.

Comment: you can pass the .class as an argument to your method

Comment: No I cannot, because I get the name class as String from a DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the class using reflection, e.g.:

```
public startNewActivity(String activityName){
   try {
       Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(getPackageName() +"." +activityName);

       Intent myActivity = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, clazz);
       startActivity(myActivity);

   } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("TAG","Error: " +e.getStackTrace());
   }
}
```

If you provide the full class name (including package name) you don't need the `getPackageName()` call.

Hope this helps .. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("yourPackage.YourActivityName");   

Intent myActivity = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, clazz);
```

Example :

```
Class <?> clazz = Class.forName("com.test.testActivity");
```

Answer (score 1):

> How could I get the class by the String activityName?

I think you need something like this:

```
Class<?> target = Class.forName(<yourPackage>.ActivityName);
Intent i = new Intent(Caller.this, target);
```

In your case you need to get from your database String from 0 to dot position.

**Pseudo-code:**

```
String stringFromDb = "Activity1Name.class";
int i = stringFromDb.lastIndexOf(".");
String actName = stringFromDb.subString(0, i);
Class<?> target = Class.forName(<package> + "." + actName); // getPackageName()
Intent i = new Intent(Caller.this, target);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast string to activity name. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11168994/909497) answer may be your problems solution. Hope this helps.